How to get rid of ingrown facial hair?
After a clean shave I have ingrown hair on my chin and alongside my jaw. They hurt a lot.
My barber recommended me not to use shaver at home, but instead get it done by him to prevent further ingrown hair.
But it appears to be very inconvenient.

Of course your barber is a good businessman :)

The cause of the ingrown hairs is the fact that the hairs are cut below the level of the skin, ans when they start growing after cutting, they cannot find the "hole" in the skin to get out, so they continue growing inside.
This problem is very common after hair removal procedures, on any part of the body - and that is the reason shavers for women exist - removing hair by plucking leads to ingrown hairs.

So the generic solution is to stop cutting the hairs too short in the sensitive area. Usually that happens when you cut the hairs against their direction of growing.
Usually the hairs grow towards the chin, so you should stop shaving starting from the chin towards the edges of the face.
Of course, you need to study your face, and apply the trick only in the areas with problems.
Personally I can cut my hairs as short as I want anywhere, except around the throat - where I shave only downwards. The "quality of the shave" is different and visible (I know because I received questions occasionally), but I can live with that. If you want uniform quality of shave, then shave following the growth of the hairs on all your face.

You may also try using an electric shaver, they cannot cut the hairs below the level of the skin.

A very bad solution - I mention it here only as a possibility, and as a joke - is to use open flame. It will also not "cut" the hairs below the surface of the skin - unless you thoroughly burn the skin too.
Dangers: skin burn, burning hair which is supposed to remain, strong specific stink of burned hair, setting your house on fire, causing physical damage (burns) to the people trying to save you from the fire.

Thanks sir , I was thinking of buying an electric trimmer, they seem to be very efficient.

You may also try using an electric shaver, they cannot cut the hairs below the level of the skin. Actually, they can. The mechanism pulls the hair a bit, cuts it, them the hair returns to rest under the level of the skin. However, I've never had an ingrown hair after using an electric razor.
